# How to transform with ColumnTransformer and OrdinalEncder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, mapping

I'm trying to preprocess data with ColumnTransformer but with no Pipeline. Here's the code:

```
object_pre = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
    ("ordencoder", OrdinalEncoder(mapping=mapping)),
    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(cols=ord_cols))
])
num_pre = SimpleImputer()

object_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype == "object"]
num_cols = list(set(X.columns) - set(object_cols))

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("num_pre", num_pre, num_cols),
    ("object_pre", object_pre, object_cols)
])
X_temp = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X))
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error on the last line:

```
KeyError: 'Education'
```

I am convinced that the problem has to do with the mapping variable, which is created with the following code:

```
mapping = [
    {
        "col": "Education",
        "mapping": {
            "Not Graduate": 0,
            "Graduate": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "col": "Dependents",
        "mapping": {
            "0": 0,
            "1": 1,
            "2": 2,
            "3+": 3,
        }        
    },
]

ord_cols = ["Gender"]
for i in list(set(X.columns) - set(ord_cols)):
    mapping.append({
        "col": i,
        "mapping": {
            "No": 0,
            "Yes": 1
        }
    })
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleImputer` first step of your pipeline transforms the data into a numpy array, so column names aren't available for the `mapping` in the `OrdinalEncoder` (from `category_encoder` package) second step.  `OrdinalEncoder` has a parameter `handle_missing` with one option `return_nan`, so I think you can swap the order of the first two steps and have the same effect.

(The sklearn version of `OrdinalEncoder` passes missing values along, starting in v1.0, so you could maybe revert to that, but then you'd have the array `categories` instead of the dict `mapping`, so you'd lose feature name capabilities again.)